# Gamecenter Connectivity Issue in Sandbox mode

Tags: ios, gamekit, game-center

When I try to start a multiplayer game in Gamecenter (Sandbox mode), the flow get stuck after the user accept the invite. It shows "waiting" at the inviter end and "Connecting" at the invitee end. It's happening randomly and it get connected 1 out of 10 times. 
I checked for Firewalls, and there is nothing in between the two devices. 
What will be the possible issues? Is it because of Sandbox mode?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this thread in the Apple Developer Forum:

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/199452?tstart=0